# Code fails to upload mulitple files on the same day and fails to create the next days upload and following month

Tags: php

I would like to automatically get the year, month and day. With the following information i would like to create a folder for the daily uploads.

```
$videoFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Videos/"; 
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $date->getTimestamp() . "." . $extension;
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("M");
    $day = date("d");
if (is_dir($videoFolder . $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $day)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $dayFolder.$targetFile);
    print $targetFile;
}

if (!is_dir($videoFolder.$year)) {
    mkdir( $videoFolder.$year );
    $yearFolder = $videoFolder.$year."/";
    if (!is_dir($yearFolder.$month)) {
        mkdir($yearFolder. $month);
        $monthFolder = $yearFolder . $month . "/";
        if (!is_dir($monthFolder . $day)) {
            mkdir($monthFolder.$day);
            $dayFolder = $monthFolder . $day . "/";
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $dayFolder.$targetFile);
            print $targetFile;
        }
    }
} 
}
```

EG: Today is 18/Dec/22

So if the folder does not exists create it then place the upload in that directory.

I tested it with the date set as the 23rd and no folder was created.

EG: New Years the code should automatically know and create the folder 2019 with the child folder of Jan then as Jan's child folder as 1.
End Dir result; /Videos/2019/Jan/1 then Feb would be /Videos/2019/Feb/1.

It should basically increment itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your script a bit and added realpath() to the video path just to be sure.
Can you tell if this works?

```
<?php
$videoFolder = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . "/Videos/";
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $date->getTimestamp() . "." . $extension;
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("M");
    $day = date("d");

    $dayFolder = $videoFolder . $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $day . "/";

    if (!is_dir($dayFolder)) {
        $mkdir_result = mkdir($dayFolder, 0775, true); // make new directory recursively
        var_dump($mkdir_result);
        if ($mkdir_result) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $dayFolder . $targetFile);
            print $targetFile;
        }
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $dayFolder . $targetFile);
        print $targetFile;
    }
}
```